# Let S be the plane passing through a point and contains the line

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Let S be the plane passing through the point (7,1,6) and that contains the line

**r**(t) = (1,0,2) + t(4,-1,3) where t ∈ ℝ

Q1) Find a cartesian equation of S

My attempt: I am not sure if I am doing this correctly and would like further help if I have missed something

The direction of **r**(t) is (4,-1,3) so (x-7)/4 = -(y-1) = (z-6)/3

or (4,-1,3)(x-7,y-1,z-6) = 0 which gives  4x - y + 3z = 45

Q2) Find the vector equation of the plane R which is perpendicular to S and contains the line **r**(t)

I am unsure how to attempt this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer to the first question is not correct, since $(1,0,2)$ does not belong to the plane $4x-y+3z=45$.

Let $A=(1,0,2)$, $B=(1,0,2)+(4,-1,3)=(5,-1,5)$, and let $C=(7,1,6)$. Then$$\vec{AB}\times\vec{AC}=(-7,2,10)$$and therefore a Cartesian equation of the plane $p_1$ that you're after is$$-7(x-1)+2y+10(z-2)=0(\iff-7x+2y+10z=13).$$

Now, if $D=A+\vec{AB}\times\vec{AC}=(-6,2,12)$, then the plane $p_2$ defined by $A$, $B$ and $D$ contains the line $\mathbf r$ and it is orthogonal to the plane $p_1$. The same method as above shows that a Cartesian equation of $p_2$ is $16x+61y-z=14$. See the picture below.

[image]

Comment: for p2, how would I change the cartesian equation to a vector equation?

Comment: Since $\vec{AB}=(4,-1,3)$ and $\vec{AD}=(-7,2,10)$,$$p_2=\{(1,0,2)+\lambda(4,-1,3)+\mu(-7,2,10)\mid\lambda,\mu\in\Bbb R\}.$$